# Printer prints broken image icon instead of referenced image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to print an image on a web page. The `img` tag looks as follows:

```
<img alt='testing' src='barcode.php?text=$invoice_no'/>
```

When I print the web page, however, the page shows a broken image icon instead of the actual image (see below).

What do I need to do to have the printer print the referenced image?

[image: picture of broken image icon on printed page]

here is My Script

```
<script>
function printData()
{
var divToPrintd=document.getElementById("result");//Div ID
newWin= window.open('', 'Print', 'width=100%,height=100%');
newWin.print();
newWin.close(); 
}
$('#printm').on('click',function(){
printData();
}) 
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your Javascript code? Better show us some more code.

Comment: Improved English, inlined image.

Comment: i have added the javascript

Comment: _“What do I need to do to have the printer print the referenced image?”_ - most likely: Specify the path correctly …? The code you have shown doesn’t seem to make much sense - you are not doing anything with `divToPrintd`, and I can’t see how that window is filled with any content to begin with. (Or does it maybe just load the current page in that new window again, because of the “address” `''`?) And why are you opening a new window to begin with? Most often stuff like this is better handled by providing a _print stylesheet_ that hides everything on the page you don’t want printed.

Answer (score 0):

is this code is a part of php variable? or just an html ?

```
<img alt='testing' src='barcode.php?text=$invoice_no'/>
```

If it is just an html, use it like this

```
<img alt='testing' src='barcode.php?text=<?=$invoice_no?>'/>
```

Don't forget to open short tag in php.ini .

Answer (score -1):

First of all You have to convert above image to .jpg and then use it as per requirement